# Find object in array & return object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array:

```js
vendor.grc1.items = [
  { item:item.rice,p:4,c:1,min:40,max:50 },
  { item:item.eggn,p:7,c:1,min:8,max:32 },
  { item:item.onn,p:8,c:1,min:5,max:12 },
  { item:item.salt,p:25,c:.3,min:2,max:7 },
  { item:item.grlc,p:14,c:.15,min:1,max:8 },
  { item:item.wht,p:5,c:1,min:13,max:29 },
  { item:item.ltcc,p:8,c:.6,min:3,max:6 }, 
  { item:item.mlkn,p:10,c:.4,min:2,max:4 },
  { item:item.wrmml,p:350,c:1,min:1,max:1 },
  { item:item.appl,p:5,c:.8,min:5,max:20 },
  { item:item.brd,p:12,c:.85,min:3,max:10 },
  { item:item.bgt,p:17,c:.35,min:1,max:6 },
  { item:item.rwmt1,p:31,c:.25,min:4,max:8 },
  { item:item.agrns,p:8,c:.2,min:10,max:30 },
  { item:item.watr,p:2,c:.85,min:20,max:70 }
]
```

I need to find the index of `{ item:item.wrmml,p:350,c:1,min:1,max:1 }` in the array, and remove it from the array if another condition is filled.

There is another function which shuffles indexes of objects so the object index can be different from time to time.

This is what I've tried, which doesn't work:

```js
vendor.grc1.extra2 = function() {
  if (quest.hngrkd.data.started = true) {
    vendor.grc1.items.push({
      item: item.wrmml,
      p: 350,
      c: 1,
      min: 1,
      max: 1
    });
  }
  
  index = vendor.grc1.items.findIndex(x => x === {
    item: item.wrmml,
    p: 350,
    c: 1,
    min: 1,
    max: 1
  });
  
  if (quest.hngrkd.data.done = true) {
    if (quest.hngrkd.data.started = false) {
      delete vendor.grc1.items[index];
    }
  }
}
```

Values of `quest.hngrkd.data.done` and `started` are managed by other function, which works.

Comment: I removed references to jQuery in the question as there is none in the code you've written (and isn't relevant anyway as thats a library primarily used for amending the DOM, not arrays and objects).

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator. You want `==` or `===` for comparison

Comment: `x === { ... }` that's not how you compare objects

Comment: That's why I said I'm an absolute noob, thank you for correction

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** Please note that this code is slow. You should consider keep an ID in each object, so that you do not have to compare the whole object

Try this. I added a function to check if conditions met to remove the item. Returns always true, just to show the removal

```
function isObjectEqual (o1, o2, ignorePropsArr = []) {
    // Deep Clone objects
    let _obj1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o1)),
        _obj2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o2));
    // Remove props to ignore
    ignorePropsArr.map(p => {
        eval('_obj1.' + p + ' = _obj2.' + p + ' = "IGNORED"');
    });
    // compare as strings
    let s1 = JSON.stringify(_obj1),
        s2 = JSON.stringify(_obj2);
    return s1 == s2;
}

const item = {};
let items = [
    { item: item.rice, p: 4, c: 1, min: 40, max: 50 },
    { item: item.eggn, p: 7, c: 1, min: 8, max: 32 },
    { item: item.onn, p: 8, c: 1, min: 5, max: 12 },
    { item: item.salt, p: 25, c: .3, min: 2, max: 7 },
    { item: item.grlc, p: 14, c: .15, min: 1, max: 8 },
    { item: item.wht, p: 5, c: 1, min: 13, max: 29 },
    { item: item.ltcc, p: 8, c: .6, min: 3, max: 6 },
    { item: item.mlkn, p: 10, c: .4, min: 2, max: 4 },
    { item: item.wrmml, p: 350, c: 1, min: 1, max: 1 },
    { item: item.appl, p: 5, c: .8, min: 5, max: 20 },
    { item: item.brd, p: 12, c: .85, min: 3, max: 10 },
    { item: item.bgt, p: 17, c: .35, min: 1, max: 6 },
    { item: item.rwmt1, p: 31, c: .25, min: 4, max: 8 },
    { item: item.agrns, p: 8, c: .2, min: 10, max: 30 },
    { item: item.watr, p: 2, c: .85, min: 20, max: 70 }
];

function anotherConditionIsFilled() {
    return true;
}

let itemToFind = { item: item.wrmml, p: 350, c: 1, min: 1, max: 1 };
let items_2 = [];

if (anotherConditionIsFilled()) {
    items.forEach(i => {
        // push item only if not equal to queried item
        if (!isObjectEqual(i, itemToFind)) {
            items_2.push(i);
        } else {
            console.log('found item to remove! ', i);
        }
    });
}

console.log(items_2);
```